# g:formatDate issue with java.sql.Date class instances

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, gsp, grails-4

[Java 7 - java.sql.Date](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/sql/Date.java) - uses toInstant method of java.util.Date class.

[Java 8 - java.sql.Date](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/sql/Date.java#l303) - Overrides toInstant method and now throws `UnsupportedOperationException` exception.

[grails-gsp-plugin v3.3.2 - DefaultGrailsTagDateHelper](https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/blob/v3.3.2/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/DefaultGrailsTagDateHelper.groovy#L65) - able to format java.sql.Date class instance.

[grails-gsp-plugin v4.0.0 - DefaultGrailsTagDateHelper](https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/blob/v4.0.0/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/DefaultGrailsTagDateHelper.groovy#L89) - **not able to foramt java.sql.Date class instance** because `date.toInstant()` is thowing `UnsupportedOperationException` (expected as per java 8 code).

And as per the [docs](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.html) **Grails 4 is no longer compatible with Java 1.7**.

So now is it expected that `g.formatDate` not allowing java.sql.Date class instance? Or is it a bug in the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this change was introduced at https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/commit/20e6ad461b575642263e4689de9cb1c7f33d1a7b.  If you file a report at https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/issues we can investigate.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Done -- https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/issues/50.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround --

Get milliseconds from `java.sql.Date` class instance and pass that in the taglib.

```
g.formatDate(date: date.getTime(), format: 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```